# Objective C - Hiding UINavigationController & UITabBarController with animation

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm working on an app that has a UITabBarController at the bottom and UINavigationController at the top of the screen.

One of the section that can be accessed through UITabBarController is a "photo gallery" section, where I can view the photo in full screen.

I'm able to hide them WITHOUT animation using the following code

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:TRUE];
```

How can I hide UINavigationController & UITabBarController with a little fade animation just when I want to view the photo in full screen? (Just like how the Facebook app hides them when you want to view the photo full screen)

Or is there an even better approach than what I'm doing as per the code snippet?

Thank you,
Tee

Comment: This almost do the navigationController part [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];. But it slides up and not fades.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make your own animation. You can use the following code...

For the UINavigationController:

```
[UINavigationBar beginAnimations:@"NavBarFade" context:nil];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 1;
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO]; //Animated must be NO!
[UINavigationBar setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn]; 
[UINavigationBar setAnimationDuration:1.5];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0;
[UINavigationBar commitAnimations];
```

For the UITabBarController:

```
[UITabBar beginAnimations:@"TabBarFade" context:nil];
self.tabBarController.tabBar.alpha = 1;
[UITabBar setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn]; 
[UITabBar setAnimationDuration:1.5];
self.tabBarController.tabBar.alpha = 0;
[UITabBar commitAnimations];
```

You can also choose a different `UIViewAnimationCurve` for different types of fading, or change the duration of the animation by giving the `setAnimationDuration`message a different input (it's time in seconds).

Edit: For the "reappearing" fade animation you would simply reverse the alpha values, so that you go from 0 to 1. If you wanna see the code for this just leave me a comment.

Comment: Works well. If you have a translucent navigation bar (which is probably recommended for this case), the `setNavigationBarHidden` call is not needed.  Also, I dropped the first `navigationBar.alpha = 1` statement, as it's not required – the fade will then start at whatever the current alpha value is.